# Cakephp: check if data exist before saving

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, save

I am currently working on my cakephp app I have database named `time`, and it has two tables: `users and accounts`.

The `users` table has EmployeeId and  Password data fields 
The `accounts` table has also EmployeeId , Password etc..

Now, what I want to happen is every time I add data to users table it will check  if that data to save already exists in the accounts table, if not it will flash error else it will save.

How can i do this in cakephp? Here is code:

**add.ctp**

```
public function add()
    {
        $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
            if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('Logs has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error(__('The logs could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
        $this->set(compact('user'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
    }
```

Comment: Use a unique field 

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html#custom-validation-rules

Comment: how is that possible if i use unique field it will just say data to be inserted must be unique all i wan to happen is before my data is save in the table users if will check if that EmployeeId and Password also present in the accounts table j

Comment: Don't mind your comment is not clear what actually you want ? If you want to create all field unique then do it, read the doc please.

Comment: check is link out for better explanation http://i66.tinypic.com/rc58hh.png

Comment: Add your add.ctp employid field.Is it cakephp 2 or 3 version ?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by this way

in your add method you can check your `Employid` with your request data.

For example

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {

            $employid = $this->request->data('employid');   //make sure your field name 

            $this->loadModel('Your Employ model');  // add your employ model 
            $check = $this->Employ->find('count')
                                  ->where(['Employ.employid' =>$employid ]);
            if($check!=0){
            $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
            if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('Logs has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
               } else {
                  $this->Flash->error(__('The logs could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
                }
            } 
           else 
           {
               echo "error message if not found";
           }

}
```

I think you get the logic.